# MySQL query with a date range selection but also need to grab the highest value of one column when another column has duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query that works great when i don't try the 'IN' query.  The query needs to select all rows between the two date variables from user input and also not be equal to ''.  My goal is if the 'item_number' column has duplicates i need to only grab the highest 'id' row.  Is this possible?

Here is my query that i am trying but not working:

```
SELECT item_number
     , description
     , style_number
     , prod_attribute_1
     , prod_attribute_2
     , prod_attribute_3
     , prod_attribute_4
     , prod_attribute_5
     , date_of_entry
     , id 
  FROM import_items 
 WHERE date_of_entry between '$finalStart' and '$finalEnd' 
   AND TRIM(style_number) <> '') IN (SELECT item_number
                                          , MAX(id) 
                                       FROM import_items 
                                      GROUP 
                                         BY item_number);
```

Here is a sqlFiddle i set up:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6c36d/1

The outcome should be all rows but only choose the highest 'id' when the 'item_number' is the same.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, consider whether your schema is adequately normalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.
I have updated my answer. please check.
Hope this will solve your issue. If not let me know I will update my answer.

```
    SELECT MAX(id), item_number, style_number, date_of_entry 
  FROM import_items 
  WHERE id IN 
          (SELECT id FROM import_items where (date_of_entry >= '12/07/2016' 
                                   AND date_of_entry<='12/11/2016') 
                                   AND TRIM(style_number) != '' ) 
  GROUP BY item_number;
```

SQL Fiddle Link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0303e/14

Comment: sqlfiddle isn't currently working for me on any browser.

Comment: I made a link for a sqlfiddle and put it in my question up top.